# How does a Function in a Function work in R?

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if someone could help me understand what this function in R is doing. I created my own function, but I don't understand how I got the output?

```
add.me <- function(x) function(y) y+x
add.me.one <- add.me(1)
add.me.one(10)
```

The following is the output

**[1] 11**

Comment: type `add.me.one` (no parentheses) to see what it looks like inside: `function(y) y+x
<environment: 0x000000000c6c30a8>`. (you can very safely ignore everything after `<environment...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add.me` returns the inner function.  Note that the inner function refers to `x` in the outer function so `add.me(1)` returns the inner function such that when the inner function is run and looks for `x` it will use 1.  Finally we run the returned inner function using y = 10 so when it is run it will use y=10 and x=1.